# Show $M_1^\perp \supset T^*(M_2^\perp)$

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

In this proof, I am confused why $Tx\in T(M_1)$. Since $x\in M_1^\perp$ wouldn't $Tx \in T(M_1^\perp)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure they meant to say $x \in M_1$, since that way $Tx \in T(M_1)$ and thus perpendicular to $y$.

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing! Yes, it's definitely a typo in the book.

Comment: Oh ok perfect. Thank you! I really appreciate the help. :)